# Python3.8 добавить значения в ключ в dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть словари с такой структурой

```
{'test': 'привет' , 'numbers': ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']}
```

и

```
{'numbers': ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6']}
```

Нужно сделать чтобы был такой результат:

```
{'test': 'привет' , 'numbers': ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']}
```

У меня пока выходит только так

```
{'test': 'привет' , 'numbers': ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']['2', '3', '4', '5', '6']}
```

Т.е. нужно их соединить и убрать дубли. Что-то уже второй день голову ломаю, не могу разобраться. Помогите пожалуйста?

Comment: Вы храните строковое представление списка или мне показалось? (у Вас в вопросе не закрыта кавычка `"`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если это всё же списки, объединяем их, убираем дубли, делая сет, сортируем

```
d1 = {'test': 'привет' , 'numbers': ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']}
d2 = {'numbers': ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6']}
d1['numbers'] = sorted(list(set(d1['numbers']+d2['numbers'])), key=lambda x: int(x))
print(d1)

{'test': 'привет', 'numbers': ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']}
```

Comment: Объясните эту конструкцию пожалуйста. Третью строчку

Comment: дак в первой строке все действия последовательно описаны, а кей позволяет сортировать строкиЮ как числаэ

Answer (score 3):

Ваш вопрос необходимо конкретизировать, а пока отвечу на оба варианта событий.

## Вариант 1

В `numbers` хранится строковое представление списка

```py
{'test': 'привет' , 'numbers': "['6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']"}
```

В таком случае вы можете использовать модуль `json`, чтобы превратить строковое представление списка в обычный список:

```py
>>> n1 = {'test': 'привет' , 'numbers': "['6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']"}
>>> json.loads(n1['numbers'].replace('\'', '"')) # обязательно заменяем одинарные кавычки на двойные, т.к. в JSON не используются одинарные кавычки
['6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
```

Тогда решение вашей задачи будет выглядеть так:

```py
import json

n1 = {'test': 'привет' , 'numbers': "['6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']"}
n2 = {'numbers': "['2', '3', '4', '5', '6']"}

n1.update({'numbers' : str(list(sorted(list(set(json.loads(n1['numbers'].replace('\'', '"')) + json.loads(n2['numbers'].replace('\'', '"')))))))})

print(n1)
```

Результат:

```py
{'test': 'привет', 'numbers': "['10', '11', '12', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']"}
```

---

## Вариант 2

В `numbers` хранятся сами списки

```py
{'test': 'привет' , 'numbers': ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']}
```

Это более простой случай, для которого не нужны дополнительные модули:

```py
n1 = {'test': 'привет' , 'numbers': ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']}
n2 = {'numbers': ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6']}

n1.update({'numbers' : sorted(list(set(n1['numbers'] + n2['numbers'])))})

print(n1)
```

Результат:

```py
{'test': 'привет', 'numbers': ['10', '11', '12', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']}
```